# Node.js - Socket.io, Express 3, Sessions. My cookie is always null. Why?

Tags: node.js, sockets, cookies

Ok, so I am relatively new to Node.js.

I am trying to get sessions to work and be accessible in my socket.io methods.

I found this wonderful tutorial and some additional code here:

http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth/server.js

I ended up with the code you see below. Now the strange part is this was working just fine all day today...I was doing some simple Jade and CSS work and it stopped passing the cookies in the header (in other words it never gets passed that first if statement).

I am using a redis store that has been working like a champ until now.

I read around and some people said to use the IP rather than localhost (i.e. :[Can't get Express session ID from cookies w/ Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359333/cant-get-express-session-id-from-cookies-w-socket-io)), but that didn't seem to help me much.

I have tried messing with which port I am using...that didn't do anything.

Underneath the code I put in a dump of the handshakeData.headers object...not sure what I am looking at there.

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {
    if (handshakeData.headers.cookie) {
        handshakeData.cookie = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
        handshakeData.sessionID = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(handshakeData.cookie['express.sid'], 'big pixel is awesome');
        handshakeData.sessionStore = sessionStore;

        sessionStore.get(handshakeData.sessionID, function (err, session) {
            if (err || !session) {
                // if we cannot grab a session, turn down the connection
                accept('Error', false);
            }
            else {
                // save the session data and accept the connection
                handshakeData.session = new Session(handshakeData, session);
                accept(null, true);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log('BAD - No cookie for you.')
        return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }

    accept(null, true);
});
```

HEADER DUMP

```
{ headers: 
   { host: '127.0.0.1:65258',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36',
     origin: 'http://localhost:65258',
     accept: '*/*',
     referer: 'http://localhost:65258/',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
     'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8' },
     address: { address: '127.0.0.1', port: 65333 },
     time: 'Sun Nov 10 2013 23:28:09 GMT-0500 (EST)',
     query: { t: '1384144089105' },
     url: '/socket.io/1/?t=1384144089105',
     xdomain: true,
     secure: undefined,
     issued: 1384144089109 }
```

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**
Ok, so I played around some more and changed it from a secured cookie to not one...like so:

```
// Configuration
app.configure(function () {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());

    app.use(express.session({
        secret: "SECRET!!",
        store: redisStore,
        key: 'express.sid',
        cookie: { secure: false, maxAge:86400000 } // <-- I changed this from true to false
    }));
    app.use(app.router);
});
```

This seemed to have fixed it but I still don't understand why this would change whether or not cookies were sent in the first place...

Comment: Secure cookies are only sent (from server to client) over an HTTPS connection.

Comment: But it worked for several hours...so odd.